# Mq6 Compcode =2 CompletionCode=2 ReasonCode=2012

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, ibm-mq

MQ6 Giving Error message as "Application Error" while initializing MQQueueManager. In Error Details i have found Compcode =2 CompletionCode=2 ReasonCode=2012 (MQRC_ENVIRONMENT_ERROR). How can i resolve this error.

mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(mqManager, channel, ipAddress);

Comment: Please also note MQ V6 is out of support, suggest you upgrade.

Comment: The votes to close that are accumulating are due to the lack of information in the post.  As Morag notes, the possible reasons for this error code vary widely.  It isn't possible to give a better answer than she has without an update to the question.  Please click "Edit" under the question and update with more detail before more close votes show up.

Answer (score 2):

The description of the error code you have encountered, [MQRC_ENVIRONMENT_ERROR (2012)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q040860_.htm) contains a number of possible reasons for this error being returned in the fully managed .NET environment (which I am assuming is your environment from the tags on your question). I repeat the list here:-

- Unmanaged channel exits
- Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)
- XA Transactions
- Communications other than TCP/IP
- Channel compression

If you are using any of these features when you attempt to connect to the queue manager then you will receive this return code.